# Adding Difficulty to a game

Tags: java, android

I want to add a difficulty in my game, for example when I click a category like category "A" it will show to the next layout and the user has to pick a difficulty to play "easy, normal or hard" .

sorry for my bad sentence

here is my categories:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.category);

        Button A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_a);
        Button B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_b);
        Button C = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_c);
        Button D = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_d);
        Button E = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_e);
        Button F = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_f);
        Button G = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_g);
        Button H = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_h);
        Button I = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_i);
        Button J = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_j);

        A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

            }
        });

 B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));
                }

        });

 C.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg2) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });
 D.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg3) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });
 E.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg4) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });
 F.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg5) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });
 G.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg6) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });
 H.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg7) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });
 I.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg8) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });
 J.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg9) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, DifficultyActivity.class));

        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. You need to do your own research and make an attempt at writing your own code. @David G. has provided links to tutorials. If you get stuck writing your solution feel free to post a new question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You should use radio buttons, so the user can select only one option and not two or more.

This is an example taken from [the official android devs website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html).

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

PS: You're question is not really clear. It makes it difficult to help you. I hope my answer is acceptable. Refer to the manuals and do [some tutorials](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/tutorials/android-tutorials/android-game-tutorials/).

Comment: sorry sir i want to add my codes but i don't know how to add it.. sorry